How to calculate minutes between 2 dates with time excluding minutes of weekend days in Oracle?
i saw many posts regarding this but all is related to business hours. My case is different, i just want to calculate minutes between 2 dates (and time)  excluding weekend days
Example
enter image description here
it should be status_date - create_date
Thank you

I didnt find same. They all calculate days and i want to see exact minutes between 2 oracle dates (with time)

Exactly the same logic as the linked duplicate, just don't TRUNCate the start and end dates and then multiply by 24*60 to get minutes rather than days fiddle

@Ina You're right. Use TRUNC (start_date, 'IW') + 5 - start_date  for getting the days (plus fractional part) from start_date to the end of Friday of the same week. Use end_date - TRUNC (end_date, 'IW') for getting the days (plus fractional part) from the beginning of Monday (of the same week as end_date) to end_date. Then use (TRUNC (end_date, 'IW') - TRUNC (start_date, 'IW') + 7) / 7 * 5 from getting the working days (plus fractional part) in the weeks in between (just verify it's a positive number). Sum up all. Multiply the result by 24 * 60 and you'll have the number of minutes.
